# PHP MySQL Insert / Select multiple one to Many

Tags: php, mysql

I've been struggling with this one for a while, and have searched various sources (books / the web / this site) but not found a solution yet. I haven't been using PHP / MySQL for that long, so I may not know the relevant vernacular to be able to target my search. Anyway...

I have a basic order management system. The customer can enter multiple lines for an item they want tested, each line having the item to be tested, and the suite of tests required. I then need to expand each of these items into its constituent tests for the test lab to manage its workflow. I need to be able to tie the test back to the order item, and the order.

I have an order table where the overall  order is captured with an order_id field (auto-incremented) and some other information (who placed the order etc). I then populate an order item table with the order_id from the order table and each item / test suite combination that the customer wants, each order item has an order_item_id (auto incremented).

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO tbl_order(od_date, od_customer_id)
    SELECT ct_date, ct_customer_id 
    FROM tbl_cart
    WHERE ct_customer_id='$customerID' AND ct_session_id='$sid'";
mysql_query($sql1);
// get order_id
$orderid=mysql_insert_id();

// save order details to tbl_order_item
$sql2="INSERT INTO tbl_order_item(cat_code, pd_code, pd_description, pc_code, smpl_type, test_suite_name)
    SELECT cat_code, pd_code, pd_description, pc_code, smpl_type, test_suite_name 
    FROM tbl_cart
    WHERE ct_customer_id='$customerID' AND ct_session_id='$sid'";
mysql_query($sql2);

//  update date fields
$sql3="UPDATE tbl_order SET od_date='$date' WHERE ct_date='0000-00-00 00:00:00'";
$sql4="UPDATE tbl_order SET od_username='$username' WHERE od_username=''";
mysql_query($sql3);
mysql_query($sql4);

// set the order id in the order item and lab item tables
$sql5="UPDATE tbl_order_item SET od_id='$orderid' WHERE od_id='0'";
```

That all works, however I'm now stuck when I try and take each each order item and expand it into its relevant tests. I have created a table which shows the test_suite / test_name combination, but I can't get the output inserted into the lab_item table.

```
//$sql6="UPDATE tbl_lab_item SET od_id='$orderid' WHERE od_id=''";
mysql_query($sql5);

// Expand Suite into tests in lab item table
$sql7="INSERT INTO tbl_lab_item(od_id,test_name)
    VALUES ('$orderid',(SELECT test_name FROM tbl_suite_select  WHERE tbl_order_item.test_suite_name=tbl_suite_select.test_suite_name))";
mysql_query($sql7);
```

Should I be doing this straight into the database, or should I pull the data out into variables first? If so, how?

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I've solved the problem now. Thanks for the input, if anyone is interested, this is was the query that eventually solved it. It was all hinged on calling the right table / cell in the Select for the final table. I was missing a field, so it didn't have a reference.

```
//  Insert individual tests into tbl_lab_item
$sql6="INSERT INTO tbl_lab_item(od_item_id, test_suite_name,test_name)
    SELECT tbl_order_item.od_item_id,tbl_order_item.test_suite_name,tbl_suite_select.test_name
    FROM tbl_order_item,tbl_suite_select
    WHERE tbl_order_item.test_suite_name=tbl_suite_select.test_suite_name";
mysql_query($sql6);
```

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Hi Jason - thanks for that. I'd read about the mysqli change, but wanted to get a working code set first, and then update it. I guess it's the trouble with needing it finished a week ago :-\

Comment: "and then update it" No, it is a safe bet that you won't update anything later. Call it experience or intuition.

Comment: Normally I would agree :), however in this case I'll be forced to as the future versions of PHP will mean I have to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question fully, but here are some improved queries (using pdo). I think the main point I added was the join statement in the last query. I also combined some of your previous queries to add the rows in one go (instead of inserting than updating). I didn't test anything.

```
$sqlStmt = $pdo->prepare("
    INSERT INTO tbl_order
    (   od_date
    ,   od_customer_id
    ,   od_date
    ,   od_username)
    SELECT
        ct_date
    ,   ct_customer_id
    ,   ? AS od_date
    ,   ? AS od_username
    FROM tbl_cart
    WHERE ct_customer_id = ?
    AND ct_session_id = ?
");

$sqlStmt->execute(array(
    $date,
    $username,
    $customerID,
    $sid
));

$orderid = $pdo->lastInsertId();

$sqlStmt = $pdo->prepare("
    INSERT INTO tbl_order_item
    (   cat_code
    ,   pd_code
    ,   pd_description
    ,   pc_code
    ,   smpl_type
    ,   test_suite_name
    ,   od_id)
    SELECT 
        cat_code
    ,   pd_code
    ,   pd_description
    ,   pc_code
    ,   smpl_type
    ,   test_suite_name 
    ,   ? AS od_id
    FROM tbl_cart
    WHERE ct_customer_id = ?
    AND ct_session_id = ?
");
$sqlStmt->execute(array(
    $orderid,
    $customerID,
    $sid
));

$sqlStmt = $pdo->prepare("
    INSERT INTO tbl_lab_item
    (   od_id
    ,   test_name)
    SELECT
        ? AS od_id
    ,   tss.test_name
    FROM tbl_suite_select tss
    INNER JOIN tbl_order_item toi
    ON toi.test_suite_name = tss.test_suite_name
    WHERE toi.od_id = ?
");
$sqlStmt->execute(array(
    $orderid,
    $orderid
));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't know anything about PDO (yet), but I'll have a look at this and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This should transform your code into working code:

```
$sql7="INSERT INTO tbl_lab_item(od_id,test_name)
       SELECT '$orderid', test_name FROM tbl_suite_select 
       WHERE tbl_order_item.test_suite_name=tbl_suite_select.test_suite_name";
```

I don't quite get whether the condition applied with where is sufficient, though.

Comment: Hi - thanks for this. Unfortunately it doesn't work, although I've spotted another issue. The $orderid doesn't come from the tbl_suite_select, but I thought using brackets would get around this. I do still need to identify the source table in the query though. I've tried so many variations now I'm losing track. Thanks though.